# Bad secondary monitor resolution

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor, laptop, resolution

I have a Toshiba Laptop with Fedora 22 installed, the monitor for the Toshiba is a 17 inches and I now have a RCA Tv as a secondary monitor and it worked just fine! But I tried to invert things and have the TV as the primary monitor and the laptop screen as the secondary. After I did that change in the display settings, well, I lost the resolution for the tv (which was 1366x768 I think.)

Now I have a max resolution on my Toshiba screen of 1366x768 (16:9) and the max resolution for the 32" RCA Tv is just 1024x768 (4:3). The manual of the tv says that `aspect ratio` should be `16:9`.

I tried adding a new mode with this [tutorial](http://www.martinaulbach.net/linux/command-line-magic/59-setting-higher-screen-resolution-for-external-monitor-in-ubuntu-14-10) and it didn't worked!

Do you have know any way that I can go back for the right resolution on my secondary monitor? I'm even considering uninstall Fedora 22 and install Fedora 23. Would that work?

Edit:

This is the max resolution I'm allowed to set for the secondary monitor on `Display`. Any help would be so much appreciated. 
[image: Display settings]

The TV model is: RCA RC32D2
**More information**

I tried adding the mode to the output (the tv) doing the following:
`xrandr --admode VGA1 1366x768` and the monitor goes black and the system ask me if I want to keep the changes, I say yes but the monitor comes back with the same resolution 1024x768. Sigh...

Comment: Did you try the GUI method first? As per your tutorial, it should be in: `Displays settings window (Applications → System Tools → System Settings → Displays).` Did you get an error message? Or any other message? And while we're at it, could you tell us what you mean by "everything went crazy"?

Comment: @Roflo thank you so much for the interest! I tried that and didn't work out. I edited my question an explained a little bit better, please, feel free to ask even more questions if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't add a comment.

Try to use `arandr` , that's just a GUI in fact but can be very helpful. 
Also when I had a similar problem on my notebook [ubuntu xrandr guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) helped me.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just edited my question again, I'm reading the xrandr guide and trying stuff out but without luck!